# Update script that is running in the background with command line arguments

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I want to make a script that can run in the background, but work like a command line tool at the same time. I have no experience with making daemons, so I have no idea if that could do what I am describing better.

I would like a loop that uses some values, and I want to be able to change these values through the Linux terminal.
E.g. I want it to run continuously and for me to be able to adjust some variables using the terminal if necessary, without restarting it.

Sorry for the pretty bad question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two programs -- one that runs in the background, and a second one that communicates with it to tell it to update its values.

There are various options on how to do this depending on your requirements.  One possibility is to have the background program accept TCP connections and take commands over them.  Another would be to have a configuration file that it re-reads each time it does something.  More exotic options useful in some circumstances are shared memory blocks and named pipes.

The general keyword here is "inter-process communication (IPC)."